# using greater than and equal signs in R

Tags: r

I am trying to cut a variable to create a factor with 3 with three levels "small" which is (-infinity to -1.645), medium which is (-1.645 to 1.645) and large (1.645 to positive infinity)

Comment: `dplyr::case_when(x < -1.645 ~ "Low", x < 1.645 ~ "Middle", x >= 1.645 ~ "High")`

Comment: base R you can try: `new_vec <- cut(vec, breaks = c(-Inf, -1.645, 1.645, Inf), labels = c("small", "medium", "large"))`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this using `base` R, is following the suggestion from @Ben, using `cut()` function:

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 4)

y <- cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, -1.645, 1.645, Inf), labels = c("small", "medium", "large"))
```

Is pretty easy to do this on `dplyr` as well, using the `case_when()` function, as suggested by @Phil. I would just add the `between()` function on the middle, to make the intention of the code more clear.

```
library(dplyr)

y <- case_when(
  x < -1.645 ~ "small",
  between(x, -1.645, 1.645) ~ "medium",
  x > 1.645 ~ "large"
)
```